# Dropzone.js return new ID for image after its been uploaded

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-5, dropzone.js

I have dropzone integrated in to my application all is working as expected, The issue I have is this, when I select an image to upload it posts to the controller which then uploads the image to a third party image storage place which returns a uniqueId for that image (which is working). I then try to pass this uniqueId back to the view but when ever I try to upload an image and alert the response back i.e uniqueId it keeps saying its underfined. I have used this code over and over in many different applications and I haven't experienced this issue below is my success method of my dropzone

```
 myDropzone.on("success", function (result) {
                    alert(result.UniqueId);
                });
```

This is my controller where I try to return the uniqueId, I've hardcoded the value for simplicity

```
 public JsonResult SaveUploadedPhoto(Int64 itemId)
    {
        var success = true;

        var fName = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                var file = Request.Files[0];

                if (file != null)
                {
                    var contentLength = file.ContentLength;

                    var bytImg = new byte[file.ContentLength];

                    file.InputStream.Read(bytImg, 0, contentLength);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            success = false;
        }

        return Json(new { UniqueId = "1245785487" }); // Just hardcoding the value to test the alert message

    }
```

But when I do the following instead of alerting

```
console.log(result);
```

and look in developer tool bar the following is what I see

```
{"UniqueId":"1245785487"}
```

So not sure what's actually wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to alert the UniqueId by changing result to rep (which is the response) my success method now looks like this

```
  myDropzone.on("success", function (rep) {

                    console.log(rep.UniqueId);

                    alert(rep.UniqueId);


                });
```